# Error when i calling jquery in master page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have calender datetimepicker jquery.
when I am calling this in simple aspx page then its working fine but when i am calling in the page where master page attach then its not working.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default11.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="Default11" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <link href="ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
  </head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#txt").datepicker();
});
  </script>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

That is working fine.

But when I am calling like this then its not showing calender

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CAL.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="admin_CAL" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHMain" Runat="Server">
  <link href="ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#TextBox1").datepicker();
        });
  </script>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hello Pankaj. When editing, please select the block of code, and click on the "Code Button" (1010101). Thanks, and welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.net changes the ID of your control - you see it clearly by checking the source of your generated page. Try:

```
$("[id$='TextBox1']").datepicker();
```

This checks for an element who's ID ends with "TextBox1".

Alternately, you can solve this at server side:

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker();
```

Comment: thanks but please see above code when i am calling in simple aspx page its working problem occurred when i am calling in page with masterpage

Comment: Exactly! The <asp:Content> is changing the ID of all the controls in it, so you can't match `#TextBox1` - there isn't an element with that ID. Open the page in explorer, click view source, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @pankaj - Kobi's right - when you add controls to a master page, ASP.NET will change the id's to something like &lt;input id="control100_TextBox1" type="Text"&gt;. You should either use his change to your jQuery selector, or you could change the selector to: $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>") so that ASP.NET writes out the acutal ID for the control into your selector.

Comment: Thanks to both of you its working.
i have another doubt please clear this.
if textbox within the gridview edit template then how can i call this.
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="enddate">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtenddate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("enddate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

then i call this text box for same

Comment: Not exactly - inside a template control you cannot access it directly. It is usually best to have a class, and using jQuery to select by that class. You can ask another question - I'm confident you'll get a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an element with an id of TextBox1? If you open the page in Firefox and use the Firebug console what kind of error is it spitting out?

You need to be a bit more informative for us to be able to help you.

Comment: The error console is generally a good start, but will not help you in this case: there isn't a bug in JavaScript. When jQuery can't match a rule it doesn't throw an exception, it returns an empty set that does nothing - this is by design, and very useful.